# Algorithm for creating efficient test ballots

Tags: election, ballot

When preparing test ballots for voting machines that read hand-prepared, fill-in-the-oval paper ballots, is there an algorithm to prepare the ballots to guarantee each candidate (in a certain race) gets a different number of votes? This would assure that when the machine was programmed, none of the candidates were swapped. That is, a fault where the oval next to Joe's name causes a vote to be registered for Sue, and the oval next to Sue's name causes a vote to be registered for Joe.

The ballots I'm interested contain several races, and the most challenging race allows one vote to be cast for any of 8 candidates (or a write-in).

The context of this question is election officials preparing test ballots and running them through the voting machine before the election, to make sure the machine is properly programmed. After the test, the vote totals in the machine are reset to zero for all races.

Comment: Why not "one for Joe, two for Sue, three for Harry, four for ..."  Why make it more complicated?

Comment: So far I agree with @JamesK but maybe somebody thought of something better. Also, if there were a publication that's impressive, it might make it easier to get fellow election workers to go along.

Comment: If I understand the question this comes down to "how can I generate 8 distinct numbers".  But that isn't really a complex task.  I'm minded to vote to close as off topic.  I may be misunderstanding the question, but I don't see a need for an "algorithm".

Comment: It's too complex for the Vermont Secretary of State to issue clear, step-by-step directions.

Comment: I feel there is some missing context here... Perhaps you are over thinking this.  Perhaps its too simple for the SoS to feel that instructions are needed.

Comment: Some context: election workers who often only test voting machines every other year show up with no preparation. Most haven't used algebra skills in decades. They read directions from the SOS that say something like "Prepare ballots so that each candidate receives one vote. Then prepare additional ballots with random votes so that each candidate receives a different number of votes." Another complication is that once the ballots have been marked so that the most complicated race is properly tested, more votes must be marked so all the races will be tested.

Comment: Yes,  I see.  Or rather I don't see a political question here.  I don't know why you think that algebra is needed here.  Or an algorithm to pick numbers.  The instructions seem simple enough, and do basic smoke testing of the machines. It really is "pick 8 distinct numbers" and honestly no more complex than that.

Comment: +1 Buy I’m voting to close this question because although elections are inherently political, there isn't a political answer to this question.  There is no algorithm needed to "prepare additional ballots with random votes so that each candidate receives a different number of votes", even with complex ballot papers with multiple questions.